# I Want To Set The Position Of TextField Just Above The TextField Which Will be Hidden?

Tags: ios-autolayout

Here i have three text fields ,which are set , now i want the position of third text field in place of second one,once i hide the second text field,the position of third text field should be shifted above.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rUgW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAjXM.png)
here ,this should look like this 
please note : i am beginner in auto layout,so if possible please send the screenshots ,as i can understand visually much better

Comment: are you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect your third textfield topConstraint in your class and modify this constraint with appropriate value like this.

```
    self.topConstraint.constant = topConstraint.constant - 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```